# Relationship between WCF Operation Name and Action

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a WCF service defined like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://AttributeServiceNameSpace", Name = "AttributeServiceName1")]
public interface IHelloIndigoService1
{
    [OperationContract(Name="AttributeOperationName11", Action = "aaa2")]
    String HelloIndigo11();


    [OperationContract(Name = "AttributeOperationName12", Action = "aaa1")]
    String HelloIndigo12();
}
```

And I captured the HTTP message during the service invocation, as below.

POST http://xxx/Service.svc/IHelloIndigoServiceAddress1 HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

SOAPAction: "**aaa2**"

Host: shao-02.fareast.corp.microsoft.com

Content-Length: 162

Expect: 100-continue

Connection: Keep-Alive

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
     <AttributeOperationName11 xmlns="http://AttributeServiceNameSpace"/>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So we can see the Action and Operation Name both exist in the SOAP message to invoke the service.

But I just wonder:
Why do we need the **Action** and the **Operation Name** to identify a single service method? Only one should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Action` and `OperationName` to identify service operation. Operation name defines structure (wrapper element name) of the SOAP message but it is not used for operation identification. The action is used for operation identification.

There are some non standard SOAP parsers using operation name (root body element) for operation identification but those parsers don't use SOAP action.

Edit: I had a discussion with my colleague today and it looks like my previous answer isn't correct. The real unique identification of the message in SOAP protocol is SOAP Action + Root element. So in this case the `Action` defines SOAP Action and `OperationName` defines wrapper element's name (used as root message element).

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't get why we still need the OperationName? If the Action can identify the service operation, why not just use the Action value as the SOAP wrapper element name?

Comment: For example because this way you can have multiple actions with same wrapper element but more important reason is interoperability. WCF can be used to expose services to other platforms but also to consume services from other platforms and you need way to separate action and wrapper element name. Wrapper element is just part of message serialzation.